# Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::loadTCA()

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Trying to install RAW HTML extension (now I know it was stupid), got Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::loadTCA()
Error thrown in file
/mnt/web116/e0/97/5985097/htdocs/CMS/typo3conf/ext/ttnews_html/ext_tables.php in line 14.

typo3 8.7.27
What should I do now? Have I broken everithing? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would deactivate the extension from the extension manager.

If you cannot access the extension manager any more, you can remove offending extensions by adjusting the PackageStates.php.

If it is something that has been cached, you can delete ./typo3temp and let the install tool recreate it.

Comment: Thanks! Next time I'll be aware

Answer (score 0):

loadTCA() has been removed in TYPO3 v7: 
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.0/Breaking-61785-LoadTcaFunctionRemoved.html

EXT:ttnews_html is outdated (over 10 years old!).

Please use maintained extensions and those that fit your TYPO3 version.